# A function to only select the column names from a MYSQL update statment

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string (MYSQL update statment):
`$string = "UPDATE myTable SET grade=99.9, name='moe', city='Taiz',pass_id=0202 where ID=99";`

I want a PHP function to help me get the column names so the strings becomes like:
`$columns = "grade,name,city,pass_id";`

I tried using this code but didn't work, like expected:

```
 $beginningPos = strpos($string, '=');
    $endPos = strpos($string, ',');

    $textToDelete = substr($string, $beginningPos, ($endPos + strlen($end)) - $beginningPos);

    return str_replace($textToDelete, '', $string);
```

Comment: Are you trying out to find out the fields which got affected after the update?

Comment: Yes basically I would like to print the table with effected fields and rows after the update.

Comment: Finding the affected rows after update already answered here.:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875263/finding-affected-fields-in-mysql-update-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this script

```
//use strtolower($string) if needed
$string = "UPDATE myTable SET grade=99.9, name='moe', city='Taiz',pass_id=0202 where ID=99"; 

        if ( strpos($string, 'where') !== false){
            $string = explode('where', $string);
            unset($string[1]); 
        }

        $exp = explode('=', $string[0]);
        $columns = ''; 
        foreach ( $exp as $e ) {
            $res = str_replace(',', ' ', $e);
            $res = explode(' ', $res); 
            $res = array_pop($res); 
            if ( $res)
                $columns .= $res .','; 
        }
        $columns = rtrim($columns, ',');
```

**Output**

```
string(23) "grade,name,city,pass_id"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly :) thank you so much... Note at first it didn't work because "where" was capital in my original script.. i changed it to small letters and it worked.